# Target CSS and JS to specific tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have three tables on a page, there are some responsive features I want applied to 2 of the 3 tables- the 3rd is just a basic 2 column table. The problem I am having is that the css + js is also applying globally to all tables including the third table which I more or less just need as basic without any js bells and whistles.

I have tried applying a class to the table and looking over the script but was unable to fix the issue.

https://codepen.io/GideonB/pen/rgWgPm I recreated the issue in this pen so that you can see as its a bit extensive. Basically the third smaller table has two columns but once the screen size is reduced below 1024px it reduces to one column (inheriting the styling I want applied only to the two larger tables) while hiding the other. Below is the script I am using.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
var pos = $(this).index() + 2;
$('tr').find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
$('td:nth-child(' + pos + ')').css('display', 'table-cell');
$('tr').find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
$('li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});

// Initialize
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)');

// Add Event Listener
mediaQuery.addListener(selectElement);

// Function Event Listener
function selectElement(mediaQuery) {
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
$('.sep').attr('colspan', 5);
} else {
$('.sep').attr('colspan', 2);
}
}

// On Load
selectElement(mediaQuery);
```

Any and all help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Basically I just can't seem to figure out how to target the two tables specifically and leave the third alone. Any changes I make to the two upper tables effects the smaller one.

Comment: Not fully understanding your question but couldn't you target the tables with it's ID to ensure it is added to the correct table?

Comment: @Si8 Sorry, I can clarify. Basically I only want the JS & CSS to target two specific tables and apply the function and styling when it hits a break-point only to those two tables while not impacting a third table at all. Currently, when I reduce the screen size to 1024px (the break point) the two tables I want effected function as I want, however, the third table is also being effected which I do not want. I attempted to target the tables I want effected with their ID's but it didnt seem to work? It's possible I may have done it wrong though, just not sure where I messed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your css outside of your media query, worked for me see code pen below:

```
table.si-cov-tb td{
 display: table-cell;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/LarryGRobertson/pen/gJgaWO)

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it! I really appreciate it, I was stumped thinking I screwed up somewhere in the script.